# Cannot access data from FCM push notification inside the callback for IOS

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am using firebase FCM to send notifications to users on my App. I am able to send notifications fine, but when trying to access the data for the notification inside the callback function nothing happens...

Here is my code:

```
//Firebase cloud function RTDB Trigger:

exports.cannectionPostNotification = functions.database.ref('/feed/{userId}/{postId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.userId;
  const post = snapshot.val();

  const ref = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/notificationTokens`);
  return ref.once("value", function(snap){
      const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: `New Post from ${post.username}`,
                body: post.capText,
            },
            data: {
              //need to access this to navigate to 
              //this screen when the notification is open...
              screen: 'imageScreen'
            },
      };

        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(snap.val(), payload)
  }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
  });
});



//App.js callback..

this.notificationOpenedListener = fire.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
    const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
    const { screen } = notificationOpen.data;
    this.showAlert(title, body);
    //alert won't show when app opens from notifiation...
    alert('NOTIFICATION OPENED' + screen);
});
```

My goal is to navigate to the appropriate screen based off the data from the payload, but I cant get anything back from the callback.

I appreciate all the guidance I can get with this issue,

Thanks!

Comment: On Android, unfortunately there is no way to access the title and body of an opened remote notification. You can use the data part of the remote notification to supply this information if it's required. From [here](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/receiving-notifications#4-Listen-for-a-Notification-being-opened)

Comment: Hi Kato, I don’t need the title and body it’s just the data in the data payload I am trying to access (screen)

Comment: @Kato it is also for IOS.